# How can I open a cygwin terminal?

Tags: windows, cygwin

I'm using a windows 8 and have cygwin installed.  However, when I navigate to the folder it's contained in, the only subfolders are usr and var, and neither contains something that looks like a terminal.  How can I open a cygwin terminal?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use `mintty` executable for this. In case of a default install path it is located here: `c:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe`
Cygwin installation puts a shortcut to the start menu, but perhaps this feature was broken in win8.
I checked this shortcut on my computer, and it contains this command as a "Target":

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

You should create a shortcut like this. Replace the given path, if your cygwin is located anywhere else. `-i` command line argument is not necessary. For further info check the manual page of `mintty`, which is located [here](http://mintty.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1127/trunk/docs/mintty.1.html).

Comment: Works from cmd and Far, yet not from sTabLauncher with icon(((.  Without icon runs OK.

Comment: I have tried several ways to provide icon with windows or cygwin path, both absolute and relative, but none worked.

Comment: manual page link is broken, think this replaces it: https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html

Answer (score 6):

You can run

c:\program files\cygwin\bin\bash.exe

inside the Windows CMD.

Comment: program files\cygwin doesn't exist for me.  Does this mean I need to re-install cygwin?

Comment: Running directly `bash.exe` inside Windows CMD did not work for me, I should have added options `--login -i` to make simple commands like `ls` work.

Answer (score 3):

When you install cygwin, it normally installs a ".bat" file at the top of the directory-tree containing cygwin, which can run a command-window.  For example:

```
﻿@echo off

C:
chdir C:\cygwin64\bin

bash --login -i
```

The exact location of the cygwin tree is relevant to the *script*, of course, and details change occasionally.  But the `bash` executable, starting in cygwin's bin-directory is enough to start a window.

Outside cygwin, you will not see things such as mounted directories and symbolic links.  So (from the Windows file explorer) it may look incomplete.